# How to create a trigger to insert grouped data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, mariadb

I'm trying to create a trigger in my MySQL server which updates all rows in a table if value changes in another. Basically, when I update a value in a table, the trigger should select a couple of columns without repeating repeated values ( we can use group by ) and store all of those columns in the second table.

I tried using group by clause but didn't work as expected.

It shows error and I can't figure out why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_update_current_movie
AFTER UPDATE ON screening_time
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS current_movies;
CREATE TABLE current_movies(movie_id INT, movie_name VARCHAR(50)); 
INSERT INTO current_movies SELECT movie_id,movie_name FROM screening_time GROUP BY movie_id;
END;
```

Comment: Which error is shown?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE current_movies; ' - You haven't defined any columns AND I don't think you want to drop, create and populate current movies FOR EACH ROW AND on an update trigger I would expect some reference to NEW. values..

Comment: So we should somehow find if the value exists in the first table at least once. How do we check that without dropping the table and creating another?

Comment: @TheUnicodist: ... well, you don't necessarily have to pre-check, there are `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` or the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` possibilities, depending upon which may be a better option for your need. Assuming that your id column is an auto increment, and the `movie_name` is not a unique index, then the `movie_name` likely needs a unique index to avoid duplicate names to use the suggested possibilities.